# Macbook Air suddenly will not power on without charger and shuts down without

Tags: battery, charging, power

I have a Macbook Air model A1466 (mid 2013 model). I replaced the battery early 2020. It worked as normal again until now. It suddenly switched of randomly and after doing this for a day or 2 it will not start unless on the charger. Even worse, when it enters standby mode, when the lid is closed or when the charger is disconnected it will immediately shut down hard. When the charger is reconnected I need to press the power button to do a cold boot.

First guess was the battery. But when i run `system_profiler SPPowerDataType` it gives me this:

```
Battery Information:

      Model Information:
          Manufacturer: SMP
          Device Name: BQ20Z451
          Pack Lot Code: 0
          PCB Lot Code: 0
          Firmware Version: 2
          Hardware Revision: 00aa
          Cell Revision: 1
      Charge Information:
          Fully Charged: No
          Charging: No
          Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 7094
          State of Charge (%): 95
      Health Information:
          Cycle Count: 124
          Condition: Normal
```

To me this seems that the battery is ok.

Same when I run a demo version of the app Watts:

[image: Watts output]

I also tried to do a reset of the SMC but that did not change anything.

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic board is likely starting to go. The battery is in good health but chances are there are other components failing.